# change array pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, shift

I have a fixed size array and i want to 'left shift' it.

e.g  {1,2,3,4} --> {2,3,4}

from my understanding arrays are consecutive memory cells, so this should be possible by just changing the start pointer.

is this possible in C?

I tried

```
array = &array[1];
```

but I get
`error: assignment to expression with array type`

I can do

```
char* array1;
array1 = &array2[1];
```

and use array1, but this introduces another variable and id like, if possible, to use less memory

Comment: "_id like, if possible, to use less memory_" Please explain, editing your question, why this is an issue for you.

Comment: Your example code should include a declaration of the type of `array`.

Comment: If an extra pointer on the stack is too much memory overhead, you likely have other problems.  And consider the actual memory used for `array2` hasn't been released, so you're not saving anything there.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are different types

Comment: Just do your second solution: `char array2[100]; char *array1 = &array2[1];` An optimizing compiler will probably make this _zero_ overhead in time and space. An old maxim: _Make it right before you make it faster_

Comment: ".... so this should be possible by just changing the start pointer" No, it's not possible in C. The "start pointer" of an array can't be changed. Actually there is no such thing as a "start pointer". There is (at C level) an array identifier (array name) and you can't assign to it.

Comment: ".... if possible, to use less memory" Forget it. You are heading in the wrong direction. Micro-optimizations like "avoiding simple variables" is something you shouldn't consider at all. You can't look at C code and predict the actual memory usage for such simple variables. The compiler will do a lot of optimizations that you can't predict. Some variable will be completely optimized away. Other variables will only live in registers and consequently use no memory. In the opposite direction two char variables may take up e.g. 16 bytes of memory if the compiler decides to put padding .... (cont)

Comment: (cont) .... between and after the chars. All this is something you can't predict by looking at your C code. So just forget it. Use the variables you need (an extra pointer in this case) and leave it to the compiler. And don't be affraid of using extra and clearly unnecessary variables in your code. If it makes the code easier to read it's much better to use a few extra variables at C level. The compiler will (nearly always) take care of it and remove unnecessary variables when producing executable code

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. So this statement

```
array = &array[1];
```

is incorrect.

This introducing a pointer

```
char* array1;
array1 = &array2[1];
```

does not shift to the left elements of the array. They stay in their original positions. There is only declared a pointer that points to the second element of the array.

To shift to the left elements in an array you need to copy following elements to preceding elements. If to shift only to one position you can use standard C  string function `memmove` or to use a loop. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

memmove( array, array + 1, ( N - 1 ) * sizeof( *array ) );
```

Pay attention to that the actual size of the array will not be changed. Arrays are extents of memory of fixed sizes.

Comment: `int *skipping_first = &array[1]` gives you a "view" into the array that looks like an array of 3 elements, starting from the one it points to.  I think it's worth saying that explicitly, because that is the efficient way to e.g. pass the last 3 elements to a function that takes `foo(int *ptr, size_t len)` args.  You only want to actually `memmove` if other pointers might already exist into this array and you want them to see different contents in the original array.

Comment: @PeterCordes To shift elements in an array and to make a pointer that points to some element in an array are two different tasks.

Comment: This shifts the data (if used properly) but does not "use less memory" as the OP wants. The clue comes from `const size_t N = ...`

Comment: @Fe2O3 He wrote clearly: " have a fixed size array and i want to 'left shift' it."

Comment: True, but the reason is to "_use less memory_"... This doesn't do that..

Comment: Yes, exactly, they're different tasks, and IMO an answer would be better if it explained both.  It's not 100% clear what the OP wants, but notice how the top of their question asks for `{1,2,3,4}` (4 elements) to become `{2,3,4}` (3 elements), which looks to me like a view into the existing array.  It might not be exactly what they *asked for*, but it's the thing that's possible with very good efficiency, so should be what they do in cases where it would also work.  (They tagged [compiler-optimization] so presumably they're interested in performance?)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the "use less memory" part of the question that @Fe2O3 pointed out, so they're looking for C++ `std::vector` `pop_front` and `shrink_to_fit`.  Or in C, `memmove` + `realloc` on dynamically allocated storage from `malloc`.  (But realloc could give it a new address, invalidating pointers into it.)

Comment: Actually, as Craig Estey comments, they might just be wanting to avoid using extra memory to hold the pointer variable itself.  (Which is often a non-problem; it will typically optimize away into a register.)

Comment: @PeterCordes C++ vector can't guarantee "less memory". And the overhead involved will use more memory than "saved" by "releasing" 1 data element. Using C and realloc can avoid the need for an extra pointer but dynamic memory also involves overhead. Further, shrinking by one data element is unlikely to release memory that can be used for other things. I think OP is looking for "memory optimization" that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SupportUkraine: Yeah, freeing 1 element isn't worth it.  I was treating it as a base case / MCVE for shrinking a larger array by multiple elements, especially one where the `std::vector` control block was small relative to the array size.  But if they were trying to save the space of 1 `int` element, you're right that's not something you can usefully do; any attempt will end up costing more data (and more code size.)

Answer (score 0):

If the array is defined as an object with local or global scope like

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

The is no way to *reduce* the memory it uses when you no longer need the full array.  You can use pointers to access portions of the array as `int *p = &array[1];` (or equivalently `int *p = array + 1;`) but it does not *reduce* the memory used, furthermore you cannot use the same identifier `array` for this because `array` refers to the array object itself, it is not a pointer you can change.

Conversely, if the array was allocated from the heap with `malloc()` or `calloc()`, you can try and reduce the memory it uses by copying the portion you want to keep over the beginning of the array and calling `realloc()` to try and discard the portion you no longer use:

```
    size_t initial_size = 1000;
    int *array = calloc(sizeof *array, initial_size);

    // ... do some work

    // now we only need the 100 elements at index 200 to 299
    // try and reduce the memory used

    memmove(array, &array[200], sizeof(*array) * 100);
    int *newp = realloc(array, sizeof(*array) * 100);
    if (newp != NULL) {
        // reallocating was successful, and newp might be different from array.
        // note that there is no guarantee any memory was actually released
        // back to the system.
        array = newp;
    } else {
        // realloc failed. While this is unlikely for a size reduction, you
        // must test for potential failure and do nothing, array still points
        // to the original block of memory
    }
```